# Test if field is null or empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried

```
if ($row_products['psText'] != empty) {
```

and

```
if (!empty($row_products['psText'])) {
```

and

```
if (!is_null($row_products['psText'])) {
```

None of them work. However, if I echo out the echo `$row_products['psText']`, it has texts in there. Am I missing something here?

Okay, I'm updating my code. Below is the whole block of code. Perhaps my logic is wrong and not the code.

```
<?php do { ?>
                <?php if($row_products['psLeft'] != ""){ ?>
                <div id="left"><?php echo $row_products['psLeft']; ?></div>
                <?php } if($row_products['psCenter'] != ""){ ?>
                <div id="center"><?php echo $row_products['psCenter']; ?></div>
                <? } if($row_products['psRight'] != ""){ ?>
                <div id="right"><?php echo $row_products['psRight']; ?></div>
                <? } if($row_products['psText'] != NULL && $row_products['psText'] != '' && !empty($row_products['psText'])){?>
                <p>
                  <?php echo $row_products['psText']; ?>
                </p>
                <?php } else {echo 'Outside texts.'.$row_products['psText'];}?>

                  <?php } while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)); ?>
```

Comment: If `$row_products['psText']` has content it is neither null or empty. So I don't see what the issue is here.

Comment: The first one is nonsense, the other two should work just fine. Please clarify what "doesn't work" means and provide a real test case we can execute ourselves.

Comment: @JohnConde He's checking that it isn't empty.

Comment: Shouldn't you try then `if ($row_products['psText'] != '') {` (it means there is no variable active or `if ($row_products['psText'] != NULL) {` But what is your goal? If you are trying to find variables that have input, than you look at it the wrong way. And you might wanna check your input always with something like a `mysqli_real_string_escape`, because of SQL injections.

Comment: `if ( empty() && !is_numeric() )` for empty non numeric values

Comment: All of these will produce a warning if `$row_products` does not contain the `'psText'` key.

Comment: I wonder, why did you tag mysql in there?

Comment: @Sergiu `empty()` will not.

Comment: you try it `if (isset($row_products['psText'])) {`

Comment: After the if statement, I use the else and it outputs the texts. But I dot not want to use else because if the field is not empty, out the texts. I do not care if when the field is empty or null.

Comment: Let's put it this way: http://3v4l.org/JZBJI It works! If yours doesn't, you're doing something else wrong and we need to see more of your *actual* code.

Comment: Do `var_dump($row_products['psText']);` and let us know what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 if ($row_products['psText'] != '') {
```

OR

```
 if (strlen($row_products['psText']) !=0) {
```

OR

```
 if(!empty($row_products['psText']))
```

I hope this helps you!!

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. I have tried all your sample code and even though the $row_products['psText'], has texts in it, it's not displaying the texts inside of the if statement. Here's the whole code.

Comment: Okay, so it seemed stackoverflow won't let me post my whole code here.

Comment: you can update your code in your question so that everyone can see that. and also check to see if your variable has only spaces inside it.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code. Again, the else statement works fine. But why is the else works when the if statement test for not null and empty? That is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

`if ($row_products['psText'] != "") {`

Comment: I tried that. It's still not getting inside the if statement even though the field has texts.

Answer (score -1):

maybe following works:

```
if($row_products['psText'] != NULL && $row_products['psText'] != "" && !empty($row_products['psText'])){
```

Comment: That it didn't work either. I put an else after this statement and the else statement does output the texts. So, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my own question. Anyway, everyone's correct with the comparing code. It has something to do with my logic.